# Bash downloading the latest version of python installer, knowing the main version

Tags: python, bash

I wondering if there is a direct link to the latest version of python installation knowing the main version.

The main idea if that I'm parsing a Pipenv file getting the required python version as:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=`grep -oP "python_version = '\\K.*(?=')" Pipfile`
```

That would give me something like 3.8, so I'm wondering if there is a direct link to something like: **python.3.8.latest.tar.gz**

**UPDATE FROM John Moon answer**

Now I can do something like

```
PY=`grep -oP "python_version = '\\K.*(?=')" Pipfile|tr -d '.'`
web_url="https://www.python.org/downloads/source/"
latest_version=$(curl "$web_url" 2> /dev/null \
                 | grep -o "href.*Latest Python ${PY:0:1} Release" \
                 | grep -o "python-$PY[0-9]*" \
                 | cut -d '-' -f 2 \
                 | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=".")

curl -# https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${latest_version}/Python-${latest_version}.tar.xz --output Python-${latest_version}.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape the version out of the Python downloads web page like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
web_url="https://www.python.org/downloads/source/"
latest_version=$(curl "$web_url" 2> /dev/null \
                 | grep -o "href.*Latest Python 3 Release" \
                 | grep -o 'python-[0-9]*' \
                 | cut -d '-' -f 2 \
                 | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=".")

printf "Latest Python version: %s\n" "$latest_version"
```

This currently prints:

```
Latest Python version: 3.8.3
```

From there, it's trivial to build whatever download URL you need. Note that this solution could change if Python changes the way their release link is formatted on the website!

Comment: Thanks a Lot I will update my question with your answer

Answer (score 1):

Well back in the day, they used to have a Python FTP site. I'm not sure it exists on its own anymore, and you probably shouldn't use it because FTP isn't secure, but there's an [https frontend to it](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/).

I'm not sure this is the correct thing to do, but you could easily download a list of Python versions using that endpoint and, fingers crossed, it seems(?) unlikely to change.

You could probably parse the output of that version listing and follow the links to download individual versions, but that seems relatively unpleasant and fragile. Having said that, it's the only solution I see for you.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/python-3.8.3.exe
```

Since you wanted tar file

```
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz
```

You can extract them by viewing the html source

Steps:

1. get the python version
2. build link with the required python version
3. automate link opening

Comment: Thanks for the direct link, the problem here is that I don't know the last part of the link **.3** part of the link